# Not able to install 'leafpop' package

Tags: r, package

I was trying to install the `leafpop` package in R. with

```
install.packages("leafpop")
```

it gives me the following error

> - installing *source* package ‘leafpop’ ...
>   ** using staged installation
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>   Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>   unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/systemfonts/libs/systemfonts.so
>   Reason: image not found
>   Calls:  ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘leafpop’
> - removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/leafpop’
> - restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/leafpop’
>   installation of package ‘/var/folders/1d/vl_b1kh51kg7j8_1250jlk000000gn/T//RtmpJM0dl8/file2657621c575/leafpop_0.0.5.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Macos, I want you to install 'xquartz' and run your code again.
I had the same problem as you.
Site is here : https://www.xquartz.org/